# Dynamically updating values of a field depending on the choice selected in another field in Django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-forms

I have two tables.
`Inventory` and `Invoice`.

**InventoryModel:**

```
from django.db import models

class Inventory(models.Model):
  product_number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  product = models.TextField(max_length=3000, default='', blank=True, null=True)
  title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=120, default='', blank=True, unique=True)
  amount = models.IntegerField('Unit Price', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

`InvoiceModel:`

```
from django.db import models
from inventory.models import Inventory

class Invoice(models.Model):
invoice_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, primary_key=True)

line_one = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', verbose_name="Line 1", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_one_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_one_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_one_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

line_two = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',  verbose_name="Line 2", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_two_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_two_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_two_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

line_three = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',  verbose_name="Line 3", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_three_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_three_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_three_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

line_four = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='+',  verbose_name="Line 4", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_four_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_four_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_four_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

line_five = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',  verbose_name="Line 5", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_five_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_five_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_five_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

line_six = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',  verbose_name="Line 6", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_six_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_six_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_six_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

line_seven = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',  verbose_name="Line 7", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_seven_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_seven_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_seven_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

line_eight = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',  verbose_name="Line 8", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_eight_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_eight_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_eight_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

line_nine = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',  verbose_name="Line 9", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_nine_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_nine_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_nine_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

line_ten = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+',  verbose_name="Line 10", blank=True, default='', null=True)
line_ten_quantity = models.IntegerField('Quantity', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_ten_unit_price = models.IntegerField('Unit Price(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
line_ten_total_price = models.IntegerField('Line Total(₹)', default=0, blank=True, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.invoice_number
```

I have a form where the person selects an `Inventory.title` in the `line_one`. I want the `line_one_unit_price` to be automatically filled according to the option selected in the `line_one`. That is, I want the amount of that product to be displayed.

[image: Screenshot of the forms]

I tried using a JSON object and then sending it to the template.

**views.py:**

```
def add_invoice(request):
  form = InvoiceForm(request.POST or None)
  data = Inventory.objects.all()
  dict_obj = model_to_dict(data)
  serialized = json.dumps(dict_obj)
  total_invoices = Invoice.objects.count()
  queryset = Invoice.objects.order_by('-invoice_date')[:6]

  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved')
    return redirect('/invoice/list_invoice')
  context = {
    "form": form,
    "title": "New Invoice",
    "total_invoices": total_invoices,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "serialized":serialized,
  }
  return render(request, "entry.html", context)
```

I am not sure how I can access that JSON file in javascript? what will be the name of that JSON object? Is it possible to access that in JavaScript? How can I use it to update the price of an item in the forms dynamically?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I added this in the HTML file:

```
    {{ data|json_script:"hello-data" }}
<script type="text/javascript">
    const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);

    document.getElementById('id_line_one').onchange = function(){
        document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = data[this.value];
    };

</script>
```

`views.py`:

```
def add_invoice(request):
  form = InvoiceForm(request.POST or None)
  data = serializers.serialize("json", Inventory.objects.all())
  total_invoices = Invoice.objects.count()
  queryset = Invoice.objects.order_by('-invoice_date')[:6]

  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved')
    return redirect('/invoice/list_invoice')
  context = {
    "form": form,
    "title": "New Invoice",
    "total_invoices": total_invoices,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "data": data,
  }
  return render(request, "entry.html", context)
```

The output I get when I select an item is `{`?
I don't know why?
[image: screenshot]

I guess it's because the logic I used in the javascript is incorrect?

JSON File:

```
[{"model": "inventory.inventory", "pk": 1, "fields": {"product": "nice", "title": "Asus", "amount": 56000}}, {"model": "inventory.inventory", "pk": 2, "fields": {"product": "nice", "title": "Lenovo", "amount": 55000}}]
```

**Edit2:**

I added this in the `script`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);

    document.getElementById('id_line_one').onchange = function(){
        var line_one=document.getElementById('id_line_one').value;
        document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = data.fields[line_one].amount;
    };

</script>
```

And now I am getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')` error. Whenever I select the object from the dropdown, It's value is stored from 1, etc. So the first object in the list returns it's primary key, i.e., 1.
I think I am accessing the fields in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve this functionality. I wish I could give the credits to a single person but it's really a combination of many people's answers.

in the `views.py` which returns the HTML page where I want this functionality, I wrote this code, It returns the Product objects to the HTML file:

```
model_data=Inventory.objects.values_list('product_number','amount')
data=[model for model in model_data.values()]
context = {
    "data": data,
}
return render(request, "entry.html", context)
```

In the `entry.html`, I access the data using: `{{ data|json_script:"hello-data" }}`

Then the data I get is:

```
[{"product_number": 1, "product": "Laptop", "title": "Lenovo", "amount": 50000}, {"product_number": 2, "product": "Single Table Tennis Ball", "title": "Table Tennis Ball Share", "amount": 4}]
```

In the `entry.html` I used some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);
    document.getElementById('id_line_one').onchange = function(event){
        var data1 = data.find(({product_number}) => product_number == event.target.value);
        document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = data1 && data1.amount ? data1.amount : 0;
};
```

So, I parse the JSON data, and then when the user clicks the drop-down menu whose id is `id_line_one`, I check if the returned number(i.e., product_number) matches with any `product_number` present in the variable `data`. and then I change the amount of that respective field.

Referrence: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72923853/9350154

Answer (score 4):

when you pass the dict_obj to your template you can get the json with

```
{{ dict_obj|json_script:"hello-data" }}

const value = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

change the value depending on the selected item

```js
const data = {
    "apple": 2.3,
    "orange": 1.7,
    
}

document.getElementById('inventory_item').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('price').value = data[this.value];
};
```

```html
<select name="InventoryDropdown" id="inventory_item">
<option value="" selected disabled>---</option>
<option value="apple">apple</option>
<option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="price" >
```

Comment: I am getting the `AttributeError at /invoice/add_invoice/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'` Error. I guess it's because I am passing a queryset instead of a particular instance to the `model_to_dict` function but the question then is, How can I convert all the objects of a particular model into a dictionary and parse them as a JSON object?

Comment: ok so your  first step should be to get / build the dict you need

Comment: I can run a for loop and store the values in a dict but I was wondering if there was a function that does this? Apparently, all the other functions just convert one instance of the model into a dict and not all instances? Do you know any functions that would be useful for this?

Comment: have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/#serializing-django-objects or https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: I updated the question. I am new to this so I am sorry if my mistakes seem too dumb. I hope you can let me know what mistake I did. Thanks!

Comment: the value of the dropdown item is used as key for the json. check out what those values are and then think how you can get the corresponding values from the json.  I would start with a simple dict. then you have a way more simple data structure to work with in the javascript.

Comment: Hey I am now able to send a string(?) back to the template with simplicity. The data I pass now is just `[[1, 56000], [2, 55000]]`. Please check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926832/accessing-values-in-a-json-array-and-then-assigning-it-to-a-textfield

Answer (score 1):

if i get it right you get the `pk` of inventory in this line

`var line_one=document.getElementById('id_line_one').value`

so you need to iterate over the json, to find it - i tested it with your printed JSON File

```
function getDictEntryByPk(dict_list, pk) {
   for (let i=0; i < dict_list.length; i++) {
       if (dict_list[i].pk == pk) {
           return dict_list[i]
       }
   }
}
```

and use it like that:

```
var line_one=document.getElementById('id_line_one').value;
var line_one_data = getDictEntryByPk(data, line_one);
document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = line_one_data.fields.amount
```

EDIT:
same with less code:

```
function getDictEntryByPk(dict_list, pk) {
    return dict_list.find(element => element.pk == pk);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy alternative would be to redefine your Inventory `__str__` method to include the unit price, so the drop down becomes e.g. 'Inventory #1 - ₹500'. You don't then need to worry about JS, JSON, or updating the amount. The total amount can be refreshed whenever the form is submitted with the quantity. Otherwise you need JS to get the unit price and to calculate the total price with the quantity.

As an aside, your models have lines manually added to the Invoice - i.e. line_one, line_two, etc. - this isn't a good way of structuring your models or data. You should add an intermediary model called 'InvoiceLine' or something similar that can handle any numbers of invoice lines and connects with FKs between your Inventory and Invoice models. The reason why this is particularly important is because at the moment all of your lines have `models.CASCADE` as the on_delete option, meaning that an Invoice with ten lines could be completely deleted even if just **one** of your FK-relation Inventory models is deleted!