# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'amount')

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-models, django-forms

I converted the Django models into a JSON data object and accessed it in Javascript. However, I cannot access a field from the object and assign it to a text box.

The `JSON` object that is being returned:

```
[{"model": "inventory.inventory","pk": 1, "fields":
{"product": "nice", "title": "Asus", "amount": 56000}},
{"model": "inventory.inventory", "pk": 2, "fields":
{"product": "nice", "title": "Lenovo", "amount": 55000}}]
```

The javascript code that I am using:

```
    <html>....{{ data|json_script:"hello-data" }}....
    <script type="text/javascript">
    const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);

    document.getElementById('id_line_one').onchange = function(){
        var line_one=document.getElementById('id_line_one').value;
        var id=line_one-1;
        document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = data[id].fields.amount;
    };

</script>....</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]
The dropdown value returns its primary key, i.e., `product_number` and basically I want to fetch the `amount` of the product associated with that `product_number`.
As the objects are stored from 0(?) in JSON, I thought the logic of my code was correct but I am not an expert so I am pretty sure I am making some silly mistake here.
How can I return the amount of the object in the `unit price` text box when the title is selected in the dropdown list?
Thanks!

`views.py`

```
@login_required
def add_invoice(request):
  form = InvoiceForm(request.POST or None)
  data = serializers.serialize("json", Inventory.objects.all())
  total_invoices = Invoice.objects.count()
  queryset = Invoice.objects.order_by('-invoice_date')[:6]

  if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Saved')
    return redirect('/invoice/list_invoice')
context = {
    "form": form,
    "title": "New Invoice",
    "total_invoices": total_invoices,
    "queryset": queryset,
    "data": data,
}
return render(request, "entry.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case is better to use array.find()

```
document.getElementById('id_line_one').onchange = function(event){
        let elementInData = data.find((item) => item.pk == event.target.value);
        document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = elementInData && elementInData.amount ? elementInData.amount : 0;
    };
```

but you can create your data as dictionary:

```
data = serializers.serialize("json", Inventory.objects.in_bulk())
```

after that you should see in javascript:

```
data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('hello-data').textContent);

// data is {1: {"model": "inventory.inventory","pk": 1, "fields":
{"product": "nice", "title": "Asus", "amount": 56000}}, ...}
```

after that you can achieve every element by key:

```
document.getElementById('id_line_one_unit_price').value = data[event.target.value].fields.amount
```

without arr.find().

Comment: I am getting this error: `(index):2267 Uncaught TypeError: data.find is not a function`. at `let elementInData = data.find(() => item.pk == event.target.value);`.

Also, I tried using `in_bulk()` But I get an attribute error saying, `AttributeError at /invoice/add_invoice/
'int' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72926832/accessing-values-in-a-json-array-and-then-assigning-it-to-a-textfield

Comment: Hey! Your code is working except that I am not sure what I must type in case of `item.pk`!! If I manually enter a primary key in place of `item.pk` I get the correct output! PLease tell me what to type in case of  `item`.pk.

Comment: you are right, here is a mistake: data.find((item) => item.pk == event.target.value);